# Name of numerical methods for second-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Numerical methods that try to solve first-order differential equations of the form:

$$    \frac{\partial}{\partial t} y = f(y,t) $$

are often Runge-Kutta methods, and there is a whole family of reasonably similar approaches.

Is there also an overarching name for numerical methods that try to solve the second-order-in-time differential equation?

$$    \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} y = f(y,t) $$

Are there (families of?) methods to solve this problem in the same way that RK methods approach the first-order problem?

Comment: Section II.14 http://thor.info.uaic.ro/~fliacob/An2/2014-2015/Resurse_MCM_2015/Hairer,%20Norsett,%20Wanner_Solving%20Ordinary%20Differential%20Equations%20I.pdf

Comment: Thanks you very much! Let me add to that also Section III.10, for Störmer Methods.

Comment: True, but RK(N) are one step methods and those are not.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean either was better or more relevant than the other, merely that there were two section describing second-order methods. So the first describes Nyström methods and the second Störmer methods.

Comment: Beeman-Schofield also provided a series of methods for second order problems stemming from molecular dynamics and  compared them with methods by Rahman and Nordsieck.